# reference request: a graduate level textbook on viscosity solutions of IPDEs

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations, optimal-control, viscosity-solutions

I am particularly interested in IPDE which arises from optimal stopping/control problems so I would like some references on integral-partial differential equations, which are related this area. I have already found

http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maxfd/viscnote.pdf

but this only seems to deal with PDEs